# Setting a windows region without disabling theming

Tags: windows, winforms, winapi

Does anyone know how to assign a window region (`SetWindowRgn` or `Control.Region` in WinForms) without killing the theming in the non-client area?

For example, running the following generates a Windows 2000-style unthemed title bar, border, etc:

```
var form = new Form { Width=500, Height=500, BackColor = Color.Azure };
form.Text = "But soft, what light through yonder window breaks?";
var region = new Region (new Rectangle (Point.Empty, form.Size));
region.Exclude (new Rectangle (100, 100, 300, 300));
form.Region = region;
form.ShowDialog();
```

I'm guessing it's to do with [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773175%28VS.85%29.aspx) which says:

> As long as a window has a non-NULL
>   region applied to it (SetWindowRgn),
>   the UxTheme Manager assumes that this
>   is a specialized window and the window
>   will not use visual styles.

...hence UxThemes assumes it's a specialized window. Is there a way to tell the UxTheme Manager explicitly to theme a window?

Comment: This is just a random thought and I'm way rusty on forms apps - but what if you put a container in the form docked on all 4 sides, and put all the other controls within it, then set the container region instead of the form region, so that the forms parent region is untouched?

Comment: @Greebo: that would result in the form showing through the "holes" rather than the other windows.

Comment: Ah - well I did say I was rusty ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is that you cannot.

But a workaround, to give you a transparent section in your form, would be to add the `WS_EX_LAYERED` extended window style to your form. Then you can tell the Window Manager that you want to use a chroma-color key to make part of your form transparent:

```
SetLayeredWindowAttributes(
      Form.Handle, //  __in  HWND hwnd,
      RGB(0, 255, 0), //green is the color key     __in  COLORREF crKey,
      255, //window is opaque otherwise  __in  BYTE bAlpha,
      LWA_COLORKEY //use color-key (rather than per-pixel alpha)  __in  DWORD dwFlags
);
```

Then you can put your "transparent" area as lime green:

[image]

Which then at runtime will be transparent:

[image]

---

**Update:** When i use layered window to have full transparency mouse events *do* trickle through to what's underneath. Notice the "flag" icon highlight:

[image]

## See also

- [Window Overview -> Window Features -> Layered Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#layered)
- [SetLayeredWindowAttributes Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Extended Window Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700543%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Layered Windows](http://Layered%20Windows)

Comment: +1 - this is what I'm doing at the moment :) The problem is that mouse events don't bleed through unless you apply WS_EX_TRANSPARENT and that effects the entire window

Comment: P.S. The fact that mouse events don't bleed through appears to be a Windows 7 / Vista bug: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/3fbfb0cc-23d4-4677-b2d6-eb0892def313

Comment: Yes: I'm using Win7 64-bit. Mouse events bleed through if the transparency key is set to black, but not for any other color! The same code works perfectly on a WinXP virtual machine, though.

Comment: @Joe Albahari: See the screenshot above? i'm using green as my transparency key; and it works fine.

Comment: Agree, but I can't use this technique unless it works on all machines

Comment: @Joe Albahari i assume you're specifying the color wrong; or there's some other error in your code. Layered Windows for color key transparent has worked since Windows 2000. Granted, it won't work on Windows 95 - but it does work on Windows 7.

Comment: I'ved tried it on other machines / configs - events bleed through for me only when DWM (glass) is disabled. The workaroud described here works: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowsuidevelopment/thread/7f44efaf-afc3-435a-8dd0-1c0146a6ee52 but unfortuntely R=G=B colors make awkward transparency keys - especially on VMs where 16-bit color is the norm

Comment: It is going to have to be an issue with WinForms, or your call to `SetLayeredWindowAttributes` - i have DWM enabled (as you can see in the screenshots) and it works fine. Are you calling `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, or is there some other property or method of a WinForms `Form` that you're relying on?