# Window regions not cutting Aero border

Tags: c#, windows-7, border, regions

I am trying to apply a region to a window outside my application using

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw);

[DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr CreateRectRgn(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2);

internal void Cut(IntPtr handle)
{
    SetWindowRgn(handle, CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 100, 200), true);
}
```

But it does not cut the window border in Windows 7. Note it is not clickable but does move when the border that is within the region is dragged.

[image: notepad is not cut properly]

What am I missing?

Comment: Well...are you sure you're picking right handle?

Comment: Yup right handle, worked with some hacks (see answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you can't according to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6313510/setting-a-windows-region-without-disabling-theming). So I figured there's two options.

### 1. Turn off Aero

[image: Windows basic theme works]

### 2. Get rid of the border

In my case I didn't need the border so I used [`SetWindowLong`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to remove it

```
var style = GetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE);
style &= ~(WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME | WS_MINIMIZE | WS_MAXIMIZE | WS_SYSMENU);
SetWindowLong(handle, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

[image: Notepad with region + removed border]